# GlusterFS help on setting up or a alternative option

Tags: filesystem, docker, rsync, btrfs, high-availability

I currently have a mergerFS mount set up with 3 disks, but want to add a way for another server so i can use docker swarm and have both hosts with the same data and setup. All I could find was rsync as a cron job, but I don't think it will work when using replication etc, I then came across GlusterFS and from what i can see will do what i need it to do, but I don't understand it fully.

My possible GlusterFS Cluster (unless there's a way without changing from mergerFS) how I need to set up is as a volume, i know i want a Distributed Replicated Volume. Currently i will have 2 hosts and 6 disks and want to have 3 disks (bricks) per host. Set out like the following (like a raid 5):

1. HOST 1

   ```
   Disk 1 - Stripe, 
   Disk 2 - Stripe, 
   Disk 3 - Stripe,
   ```
2. HOST 2

   ```
   Disk 1 - Replication Of Host 1 Disk 1, 
   Disk 2 - Replication Of Host 1 Disk 2, 
   Disk 3 - Replication Of Host 1 Disk 3
   ```

On Host 1 I have BTFS on the disks and each one mounted under `/mnt/data1 /mnt/data2 /mnt/data3`. On Host 2 I was planning on doing the same. From what i understand i need to do the following command:

```
gluster volume create pool replica 2 transport tcp server1:/mnt/data1 server2:/mnt/data1 server1:/mnt/data2 server2:/mnt/data2 server1:/mnt/data3 server2:/mnt/data3
```

Or am I misunderstanding something?

I am also trying to work out if i can mount it to /DATA on each host. Also wondering if it would be possible to add another host to it sometime to add more data size but not sure how yet?

The data is all ready on the host 1 stripe (using MergerFS). I did read you can change over by removing the volume from mergerfs and creating the glusterfs volume and moving files from the data disks to the gluster volume, which it will then sort it all out for me (hope this is correct).

Any help would be great, thanks, all.

Reading forums and the gluster docs, google and reading pages i can fine from the results